# Cassandra nodetool status shows ownership as 200%

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

After setting up a 3 node cassandra cluster (cassandra version - 2.1.9), I ran the "nodetool status" command. I realized that the effective ownership % sums up to 200%.

```
    Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  <IP>  105.35 KB  256     67.4%             <HostID>  rack1
UN  <IP>  121.92 KB  256     63.3%             <HostID>  rack1
UN  <IP3>  256.11 KB  256     69.3%             <HostID>  rack1
```

Does any one know why would we get a 200% ownership? Is it because of some replication factor? If so, how do I find out about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dependent on the replication factor of the keyspace you are displaying.

For example, if you create a keyspace like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 
    'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': 2 };
```

And then display the status of that keyspace:

```
nodetool status test_keyspace
```

Then the `Owns` column will sum to 200%.

If you used a replication factor of 3, it would sum to 300%, and if you used a replication factor of 1, it would sum to 100%.

To see how a keyspace is defined, go into cqlsh and enter `desc keyspace test_keyspace`